# Identifying and reconstructing the derived category from its auto-equivalences

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, derived-categories, geometric-representation-theory

**Background:** Given a smooth irreducible algebraic variety $Y$ with $\omega_Y$ or $\omega_Y^{-1}$ ample. Then [Bondal-Orlov theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9712029) states that if there exists any other smooth algebraic variety $Y'$ such that
$$ D^b Coh(Y) \: \:, \:\: D^b Coh(Y') $$
are graded equivalent, then $Y$ and $Y'$ are in fact isomorphic. This is known to be false for other varieties (e.g. for abelian varieties by results of Mukai and Orlov).

Similarly, Bondal-Orlov theorem includes a rigidity statement for the group of auto-equivalences: it is always true that the bounded derived category $D^b Coh(X)$ contains 
$$ A(X) = (Aut(X) \ltimes Pic(X)) \times \mathbb{Z}$$
and under the same assumptions of ampleness, Bondal-Orlov states that it is an equality. However, this is again false when $\omega_X$ is trivial (e.g. for all abelian varieties there is a strict inclusion. There are also examples with nontrivial $\omega_X$);

In fact, Kontsevich's Homological Mirror Symmetry conjecture implies that for CY 3-folds, every auto-equivalence of the split-closed Fukaya category $(M,\omega)$ (which are abundunt, since they are coming from $Symp(M,\omega)$) gives an auto-equivalence of the derived bounded category of its mirror (see [Seidel-Thomas](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001043), which produce many twists along spherical objects from generalized Dehn twists on the mirror side).

**My question:** What is known about extracting the category (and not the space!) from its autoequivalences?

That is, suppose we have been given an $A_\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$.

1. Under what conditions does there exist a smooth projective variety $X$ such that $\mathcal{C} = Auteq(D^b Coh(X))$?
2. Is there a corresponding uniqueness result of some sort? That is, I want a statement of the form: if there exists a projective variety $X'$ with $$\mathcal{C} = Auteq(D^b Coh(X'))$$ 
   then $D^b Coh(X)$ and $D^b Coh(X')$ are equivalent? (Note: this does not imply that $X$ and $X'$ are isomorphic, because of the examples above.)

---

**EDIT:** In some cases the answer to 2. is clearly negative. As Piotr pointed out (see the comment below) this is probably the case whenever Bondal-Orlov holds. But these are exactly the ''un-interesting" case - the cases where $D^b Coh(X)=A(X)$ and the category of auto-equivalences is as small as it can be.

Comment: A generic $X$ of general type will have no automorphisms. By Orlov's theorem, I think this implies that ${\rm Aut}(D^b({\rm Coh}(X)))$ is generated by the shift and ${\rm Pic}(X)$. So for hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$ ($n>3$) of general type, the automorphism group is just $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and gives you zero information. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I think it's always true that $Auteq(D^b(X))$ contains the subgroup A(X)=$(Aut(X) \ltimes Pic(X)) \times \mathbb{Z}$, and Bondal-Orlov showed that is it also equal if $\omega_X$ or $\omega_X^{-1}$ is ample. I'm asking about what happens in the other cases (e.g. there are papers by Mukai and Orlov which show that there is never equality for all abelain varieties). For example, if we consider a CY 3-folds, one can obviously obtain a lot of nontrivial auto-equivalences via mirror symmetry from the auto-equivalences of the Fukaya category.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Also, note that the question is not about reconstructing the variety ... I'm asking when does an $A_\infty$-category appear as the autoequivalence category of a bounded derived category/Karoubi-closed, idempotent completed Fukaya category. The uniqueness statement in 2. is not about $X$ - it's about uniqueness of the category $\mathcal{D}$ among all **categories** $D^b Coh(Y)$ when I write $\mathcal{C} = Auteq(\mathcal{D})$.

Comment: I'll edit to make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: "For example, if we consider a CY 3-folds, one can obviously obtain a lot of nontrivial auto-equivalences via mirror symmetry from the auto-equivalences of the Fukaya category". 

Can you actually give an example of a pair of CY-3 where homological mirror symmetry is rigorously established?

Comment: @Libli A pair? No, you absolutely right ...But Mirror symmetry for CY hypersurface in projective space with LG-mirror is established. Also Mirror symmetry for CY 2-folds like the quartic surface. When we consider open manifolds, there are many other examples.

Comment: There is also a lot of work right now on establishing HMS for K3-pairs, I think.

Comment: @Nati : I think K3 surfaces is a good example to start with. There is some recent work of Bridgeland and Bayer which more or less describes completely the autoequivalences group of $D^b(K3)$, when the Picard rank of the $K3$ is $1$. Starting from their description of this automorphism group, is it possible to reconstruct $D^b(K3)$?

Comment: @Libli Thanks! I didn't know about Bridgeland&Bayer paper. I'm going to take a look.